# SAS Two dimensional array to count missing values of character variables across rows

Tags: arrays, sas

I have a data set of 10 observations and has 6 character variables as days and cities.
Each variable has observation as either day name or missing value 'NA' for variables with day Name. Similarly,each variable has observation as either city name or missing value 'NA' for variables with City Name.
I would like to count the number of missing values in those character variables with SAS two dimensional array as part of an exercise. The log messages I have got follows the code below.

```
data want;
  set have;
  array var{2,3} i_Day5 Day6 Day7 City1-City3;
  array m{2} 8;
  do i=1 to 3;
    do j=1 to 3;
      m{i}=sum(m{i},ifn(var{i,j}="NA",0,1));
    end;
  end;
run;
```

The log shows a warning

```
WARNING: An array has been declared with the same name as a built in
or user defined function.
References to var() will refer to the array definition, not the function call.
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Array subscript 3 out of range [1-2] for dimension 1 of array m at line 254 column 1
```

The error may occur when there are nonexistent records. Please let me know any tips you have to get around this error.

Comment: change the upper bound on I loop from 3 to 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WARNING comes from declaring an array named `VAR` that be will utilized in the DATA step in place of the `VAR` function that usually "Returns the variance of the nonmissing arguments."

The ERROR occurs because the array `m` was declared as `{2}` -- meaning it has two addressable indices, namely `1` and `2`.

When the `i` loop index goes to `3` you are attempting to access `m{3}` and the ERROR occurs.

When dealing with code that loops over arrays in which the bounds may vary due to either coding experiments or macro variable resolutions the safest iterative `DO LOOP` will use `LBOUND` and `HBOUND` functions for the start and stop values.  These functions return the lowest and highest index of an array's dimension.

```
do rowIndex = lbound(var,1) to hbound(var,1);
  do colIndex = lbound(var,2) to hbound(var,2);
    m{rowIndex} = ...;
  end;
end;
```